# Assembly x86-64 get function parameters from stack

Tags: linux, function, assembly, x86-64, stack-memory

Lately I've been learning x86 Assembly from the book [Programming from the Ground Up](http://mirrors.fe.up.pt/pub/nongnu//pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf), but I have an x86-64 computer, so things start to go wrong at one point (pretty early in the book). I got to the part where I'm dealing with functions, specifically the *power* example. In this example he pushes the parameters onto the stack and then copies them into registers later in the function. Here's what his code looks like:

```
pushl $3                        # second argument
pushl $2                        # first argument
call power                      # call function
...
power:
  pushl %ebp                    # save old base pointer
  movl %esp, %ebp               # make stack pointer the base pointer
  subl $4, %esp                 # get room for our local storage

  movl 8(%ebp), %ebx            # put first argument in %eax
  movl 12(%ebp), %ecx           # put second argument in %ecx
```

Of course, this is 32-bit, and I'm running 64-bit, so I tried updating the registers and instruction suffixes to end up with something like this (comments shouldn't be needed this time):

```
pushq $3
pushq $2
call power
...
power:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  subq $4, %rsp

  movq 8(%rbp), %rdi
  movq 12(%rbp), %rsi
```

Given, I might just be confusing the actual registers I'm supposed to use, but I'm not completely sure. All I know is that when I print the value of %rdi in the GNU Debugger after the command `movq 8(%rbp), %rdi` it seems to me as if it has the memory address rather than the contents of it considering I get the following:

```
(gdb) i r rdi
rdi            0x400081 4194433
```

Also, is there something like a forum for Assembly hobbyists? I've done some basic searching but haven't managed to find one (except for a forum for x86 assembly that just has one post and it's a welcome post, http://www.x86-assembly.org/).

Thanks!

Comment: Arguments aren't on the stack in the x86-64 ABI.

Comment: qwords are 8bytes and not 4, so change this `movq 8(%rbp), %rdi` to `movq 16(rbp)` (same thing with the next line) and you could use the registers for arguments, it is required for syscalls to use the x86-64-abi.

Comment: [Why first parameter is 16($rbp) and not 8($rbp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65507658) shows an example with 10 integer args, so the last 4 actually are on the stack.  (Unlike here where you've invented your own calling conventions that uses stack-args even for the first 2 args)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard 64 bit conventions don't use the stack like that, they pass at least the first few arguments (type permitting) in registers. Of course for your own code you can still use the stack. However, you should adjust your offsets so that they use the appropriate size, 8 bytes instead of 4.

> subq $4, %rsp

You should really use multiples of 8 unless you know what you are doing.

> movq 8(%rbp), %rdi

You expect this to be the first argument but it isn't. It is actually the return address on the stack, since each item is 8 bytes now. So at `0(%rbp)` you have the pushed `rbp`, and `8(%rbp)` is the return address. Thus `16(%rbp)` is the first argument and `24(%rbp)` is the second.

Note that in most environments you can still write 32 bit code, so if you want to keep using that book you might want to do that instead of trying to adjust for 64 bit.

PS: You get a cookie for using a debugger :)